# yocto generat symlink to /lib64

Tags: yocto

I have a self written recipe for nodejs because I need a specific Version. In the recipe I generate a symlink from /lib64 to /lib. When the symlink doesn't exist I got an error when I try to run node on my device.

```
do_install () {
    # Create a symbolic link for the lib64 lib path
    install -d ${D}/lib
    ln -s /lib ${D}/lib64
}

FILES_${PN} += "/lib64"
```

I see in the build-history that the link exists but when I build the image I always get the following failure.

```
| /home/rail/yocto/build/tmp/work/odobox_e3900-poky-linux/odobox-developer-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin/prelink: Could not record directory /lib/modules-load.d: No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| DEBUG: Python function do_image finished
| ERROR: Function failed: prelink_image (log file is located at /home/rail/yocto/build/tmp/work/odobox_e3900-poky-linux/odobox-developer-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image.3534)
```

Is there another solution for the problem?!

best regards Harald

Comment: `ln -s ${D}/lib ${D}/lib64`

Answer (score 1):

Yocto introduced new linking tool "[lnr](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-2.3-absolute-symlinks)"

I created a recipe example (**lnr-example**) on a sumo build environment:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://lnr.bin"

FILES_${PN} += "/lib64"
FILES_${PN} += "/lib"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/lib/
    install ${S}/lnr.bin ${D}/lib
    lnr ${D}/lib/ ${D}/lib64
}
```

After building the example, here is the final "image" folder:

```
$ ls -l tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lnr-example/1.0-r0/image
drwxr-xr-x 2 talel talel 4.0K مارس  30 10:44 lib/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 talel talel    3 مارس  30 10:44 lib64 -> lib/
```

Remember you need to package **/lib** as well, because it will fail if it contains some content, the issue is that the parent task which is /lib is not packaged, here is the error:

> File './lib64/lnr.bin' cannot be packaged into 'lnr-example' because
> its parent directory structure does not exist. One of its parent
> directories is a symlink whose target directory is not included in the
> package.

And, adding (**IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " lnr-example"**) done without problems.

Comment: [lnr has been remove in Yocto 4.0](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/migration-guides/migration-4.0.html#miscellaneous-changes), use `ln -rs` instead.